# Optimizing recursion algorithm that take 2^n complexity

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, data-structures

I found these problem: Suppose that I have fields with N apple tree, each with A<sub>i</sub> apple on it. I also have M basket, each basket have the property C<sub>i</sub> for capacity and F<sub>i</sub> for flexibility. When I'm going to pick the apple trees I can only pick from tree in order from 1 to N. At each tree I have two options, to pick all the apple on the tree or to expand my basket to increase it's capacity by F. When I expand the basket, I cannot pick the fruit in the that tree. Find the maximum number of apple can be picked by each basket.

Example:

N = 5; A = [3, 2, 4, 7, 5]

M = 2; (C,F) = [(5,3), (3,6)]

Answer:
For the first basket the maximum amount of apple obtained is 12:

1. Expand the bag by 3 (Max capacity = 5+3 = 8)
2. Expand the bag by 3 (Max capacity = 8+3 = 11)
3. Expand the bag by 3 (Max capacity = 11+3 = 14)
4. Pick the 4-th tree (Get 7 apple, current total = 7)
5. Pick the 5-th tree (Get 5 apple, current total = 12)

And for the second bag the maximum is 15:

1. Pick the 1-th tree (Get 3 apple, current total = 3)
2. Expand the bag by 6 (Max capacity = 3+6 = 9)
3. Expand the bag by 6 (Max capacity = 9+6 = 15)
4. Pick the 4-th tree (Get 7 apple, current total = 10)
5. Pick the 5-th tree (Get 5 apple, current total = 15)

I already asked this on another SO question and got this code

```java
class Main {

  private static Map<String, Integer> cache = new HashMap<>();
  static int[] trees = new int[]{3, 2, 4, 7, 5};

  public static int maxApples(int treeNum, int capacityLeft, int basketFlex) {

    if (cache.containsKey(treenum+"_"+capacityLeft+"_"+basketFlex)) {
       return cache.get(treenum+"_"+capacityLeft+"_"+basketFlex);
    }

    if (treeNum >= trees.length) {
      cache.put(treenum+"_"+capacityLeft+"_"+basketFlex, 0);
      return 0;
    }

    int pick = 0;
    if (trees[treeNum] <= capacityLeft) {
      pick = trees[treeNum] + maxApples(treeNum+1, capacityLeft - trees[treeNum]);
    }
    int expand = maxApples(treeNum+1, capacityLeft + basketFlex);

    cache.put(treenum+"_"+capacityLeft+"_"+basketFlex, Math.max(pick, expand));
    return Math.max(pick, expand);
  }
}
```

The problem is I'll have to calculate this for up to 24300 basket with 100 tree in just 3 seconds. The code even with some more optimization can't cut it. I always get memory limit error with the hashmap or TLE. (The bound for the flexibility and capacity and apple/tree are all 1 million)

How should I optimize this algorithm?

(This is continuation from this question: [Apple Picking Optimization Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64248982/apple-picking-optimization-algorithm))

Comment: Shouldn't this be on codereview.stackexchange.com?

Comment: One thing I notice is that you do a lot of string manipulation in order to save your data structures. Maybe you could find data structures that don't have this overhead.

Comment: Compute the key for the hash map with `int key = capacityLeft * 128 + treeNum` to eliminate all of the string manipulation.